# Display progress while restoring database in linqpad with reative extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive, linqpad, smo

I have the following C# code.

```
var databaseRestore = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore();
//databaseRestore.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
//databaseRestore.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
//databaseRestore.Complete += Restore_Completed;

...

var complete = Observable
    .FromEventPattern(databaseRestore, "Complete")
    .Select(x=>x.EventArgs as ServerMessageEventArgs)
    .Select(x=>x.Error.Message)
    .Take(1)
    .DumpLive("Complete");

var percentComplete = Observable
    .FromEventPattern(databaseRestore, "PercentComplete")
    .Select(x=>x.EventArgs as PercentCompleteEventArgs)
    .Select(x=>x.Percent)
    .TakeUntil(complete)
    .DumpLive("PercentComplete");

...

databaseRestore.SqlRestore(server);
```

If I run it this, first comes always the output from handlers (if I uncomment them).

Then first, Linqpad shows the "Live Observables" result tab with

1. "Complete" observable, already finished and with final result message.
2. "PercentComplete", still waiting and with "-" (yet no entries?)

What I want is just to come away from events using reactive extenxions.
First should come the "PercentComplete" observable updated with actual progress.
Then "Complete" with final message.

The question: how do I set up the observables properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is this is the fault of how DumpLive() uses a Dispatcher on the main thread.

Are you running the database restore on the main thread, or blocking the main thread waiting for a completion signal?

I experimented a bit and ran an Observable on a background thread with a DumpLive() - if the main thread was blocked (e.g. with a Wait or a Thread.Sleep) the UI did not update.

Even if it's on a different thread, it seems DumpLive() can only update the UI on the main thread. My guess it that it needs to render updates on a Dispatcher associated with the main thread.

When using DumpLive LINQPad won't terminate execution until the observables complete, so if you have any blocking code on main thread remove it and see if it works then.

Here's my experimental code. As soon as you add in either `DumpLive()` clause in the example below, you'll see the blocking behaviour:

```
void Main()
{
    Task.Run(() => {
    var progressor = new Progressor();
    var complete = Observable
        .FromEventPattern(
        h => progressor.Complete += h,
        h => progressor.Complete -= h)
        .Select(_ => "Complete")
        .Take(1);
        // append this to see blocking
        //.DumpLive();

        complete.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);


    var percentComplete = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<PercentCompleteEventArgs>(
        h => progressor.PercentComplete += h,
        h => progressor.PercentComplete -= h)
        .TakeUntil(complete)
        .Select(i => "PercentComplete " + i.EventArgs.PercentComplete);
        // append this to see blocking
        // .DumpLive();

        percentComplete.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
    });

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

public class Progressor
{
    public Progressor()
    {
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Take(10)
            .Subscribe(
            i => RaisePercentComplete(((int)i+1) * 10),
            () => RaiseComplete());
    }

    private void RaiseComplete()
    {
        var temp = Complete;
        if(temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void RaisePercentComplete(int percent)
    {
        var temp = PercentComplete;
        if(temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PercentCompleteEventArgs(percent));
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler Complete;
    public event EventHandler<PercentCompleteEventArgs> PercentComplete;
}

public class PercentCompleteEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int PercentComplete { get; private set; }

    public PercentCompleteEventArgs(int percent)
    {
        PercentComplete = percent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do it direct in the Main() method without any other operations. Withing the `CompletionStatusInPercent` handler I have just `args.Percent.Dump();` which writes the percent 10 times in each line. The same behavior if commented out.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your RX. My example certainly shows issues with DumpLive but I can't comment further on your scenario without digging into the implementation of your code, and LINQPad itself. I suggest you mail Joe Albahari on this - in my experience he's pretty quick at responding to support requests and fixing problems.

Comment: there is almost no other code than that. Do you really suspect the DumpLive()?

Comment: Well, I suspect `databaseRestore.SqlRestore(server);` is doing work on the main thread, and that `DumpLive()` needs to schedule work on the main thread to work correctly. The latter is clear from my code sample.

Comment: Did you try `Task.Run(() => databaseRestore.SqlRestore(server));` instead?

Comment: Well... i have surroundes the entire Main() content with `Task.Run(()=>...)` and it really works! I don't like magic... Thank you anyway.

Comment: In what way is this magic? It's freeing up the dispatcher! Glad it's working for you! :)

Comment: @JamesWorld, feel free to edit my edit. Or remove it.

Comment: @Paulo I'm not sure what you intended with that edit - the point is specifically to show how DumpLive() can be blocked in LINQPad... others have rejected your edit anyway. Maybe add an answer instead? But you should clarify what you are trying to demonstrate.

Comment: @JamesWorld, just what I wrote. The same code but without unawaited calls to `Task.Run` and calls to `Thread.Sleep`. But if no one is interested...

Comment: @Paulo It doesn't solve the problem. You are on the main thread. DumpLive() would still block. `Thread.Sleep` was only there to illustrate the blocking, as a simulation of the `SqlRestore` command. I think you missed the point... this question is all about getting specifically DumpLive() to update smoothly.

Comment: It was not intended to solve the problem, just to fix the answer - that `Task`-base code is not a best practice. On my test machine the "LINQPad query" finished before the "end" of the `Progressor`. If it was a real console application it would have not finished.

Comment: But DumpLive() only exists in LINQPad. When using DumpLive() (and LINQPad in general) it's very common to keep running after the main method has executed. This isn't production code, it's an example. And your "fix" prevents the demonstration from working. The OP's code is *intended* to be run from LINQPad. My code is exactly as intended - there's nothing wrong with it. The behaviour is intentional.

Answer (score 4):

LINQPad's `DumpLive` method renders using WPF, so it cannot work if the main thread is blocked.

You could instead write your own version of DumpLive which renders using HTML. This will be slower (because it has to update an HTML DOM each time an observable posts a value), but it would work whether or not the main thread is blocked.

Here is the code:

```
IDisposable DumpLatest<T> (IObservable<T> obs)
{
    var dc = new DumpContainer ().Dump();
    var extensionToken = Util.GetQueryLifeExtensionToken();
    return obs.Subscribe (
        value => dc.Content = value,
        ex => { dc.Content = ex; extensionToken.Dispose(); },
        () => extensionToken.Dispose());
}
```

If you define it as an extension method in **My Extensions**, you will be able to call upon it whenever you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer from the first hand! The function is just what I missed. I'll take it into "My Extensions".

Comment: Won't compile for me. I get `"No overload for method 'Subscribe' takes 3 arguments"`