# How to Dump latest list in LinqPad?

Tags: task-parallel-library, system.reactive, linqpad, concurrent-collections

So the following code will do a dump of the whole list every second.

```
var list = new List<object>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    list.Add(new { A = i.ToString(), B = new Random().Next() });
    list.Dump(); // How to DumpLatest()?
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

But how can I make it to just update the dump output without adding a new one?

There is a related Q/A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578609/450913) but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You do know that calling `new Random().Next()` in a tight loop is very likely to use the same seed for all random values (and give you a stream of the same number)? Is that why you have the `Thread.Sleep(1000)`?

Comment: Good to know. Here I just wanted to have some value in there, could be empty string or anything for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `DumpLatest()` extension method only applies to `IObservable<T>`; there's no way to detect that an item is added to a `List<T>`, so LinqPad can't display the last value added.

Instead you can use a `DumpContainer` and change its content explicitly:

```
var list = new List<object>();

var container = new DumpContainer();
container.Dump();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var item = new { A = i.ToString(), B = new Random().Next() };
    list.Add(item);
    container.Content = item;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

You could also achieve the same result with a `Subject<T>` (arguably more elegant):

```
var subject = new Subject<object>();
subject.DumpLatest();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var item = new { A = i.ToString(), B = new Random().Next() };
    subject.OnNext(item);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

---

EDIT: OK, I thought you wanted to see only the last item. To print the whole list, just use `subject.Dump()`, as mentioned by Joe in the comments. If you use the first approach, put the list itself in the `DumpContainer`, and call `Refresh()` on it in the loop.

Comment: Great, but this only outputs the last item, not the updated list. I could get what I needed by doing the following: `list.Add(item); subject.OnNext(list.ToArray());`

Comment: If you take Thomas's second solution, and replace .DumpLatest() with .Dump(), does it give you what you want?

Comment: @joe-albahari Yes, awesome! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Basically same with [Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31600417/2055187)'s answer, a little shorter.

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
.Select(t=> new { A = t.ToString(), B = new Random().Next() })
.Take(100)
.Dump(); // all 100 
//.DumpLatest(); //only latest one
```